# Facing issues in Android Studio Project template

Tags: android

I've freshly installed Android Studio 2022.2.1 Flamingo in my Ubuntu 22.04.Now when I fire up the Android Studio and create an empty activity it doesn't show me the option to change the programming language to Java,by default it creates the gradle on Kotlin.I don't want that.

I did some research on it and I think that some of the Project Templates are missing in it.
[Screenshot of the Project Template available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZUJc.png)

So Please help me out of it and Thanks in Advance.

Comment: An app that use Compose can only be written with Kotlin, if you want to use Java you have to use the old layout with XML. For that you can choose the first option (No Activity) to start an empty project or any other option from the second row (for example Empty Views Activity).

Comment: Thanks for the information,I tried and it worked but does that means android studio no longer support empty activity or something?

Comment: No, the template for an empty Activity with XML is the middle one (Empty Views Activity). But since Compose has officially become the recommended framework for UI building, Android Studio's templates have been reorganized, that is it.

Comment: Thanks for this one,I was not aware of it before.